# click back button for multiples of five and quick app

Tags: android

I use the sharedPreferences to record the number of clicks.

When it gose to multiples of five , it will show a dialog and i can choose quit or not.

I try this :

```
//global
private int count=0;
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("count", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putInt("count",count++);
            int record = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);

            Toast.makeText(this, record + "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (record % 5 == 0) {
                quickDialog();//show dialog for quick
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

1.
The issue is my toast for record , it always shows 0 .

2.
and Dialog shows every click,too.

Why?

Comment: You forget to commit. But why you need to save to preference. Just use static variable.

Comment: `commit();` add this

Comment: thanks both of you , and @K. Sopheak you remind me the way , ya why i use preference....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not saving preference state ,

```
 editor.putInt("count",count++);
 //  count is not saved yet     
 int record = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
 // always get default value as zero
```

so you need to commit the value using `editor.commit` or `editor.apply`

```
 editor.putInt("count",count++);
 editor.commit();
 //^^^
 int record = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
```

Comment: thanks @Pavneet Singh , i forgot the commit , it work now.

Comment: @徐博俊 i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Commit the changes so that it persists in SharedPreference. Otherwise, it will always return default value which in this case is 0.

```
editor.putInt("count",count++);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Haha. No problem. The answer you've accepted is sure has more explanation than mine. So, no hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

commit your change

```
 private int count=0;
    @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("count", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putInt("count",count++);
                editor.commit();
                int record = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);

                Toast.makeText(this, record + "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (record % 5 == 0) {
                    quickDialog();//show dialog for quick
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the value, your `editor` is not making `commit()`:

```
editor.commit();
```